# Is it possible to tag text as italics inside the code element using MAML

Tags: sandcastle, maml

Editing MAML file in sandcastle and need to have a value appear as italic, bold, or an identifiable color within code element.

For example the following does not work:

```
<code language="xml">
 name="<legacyItalic>value</legacyItalic>"
</code>
```

Is it possible to highlight some code that will be referred to later in descriptive paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

After further research I discovered that you cannot use html markup in code element if you specify a supported language in the language attribute. Color syntax highlighting is used for supported languages. If you specify text as the attribute value, then you can use html markup such as the span element to specify a background color. Of course you then lose color highlighting for the specified language. In my case, code sample is in XML so I don't care as much about the color.